# Swift 3.0 - NSNumber and Int cannot be applied to operands

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber

```
var Rating = self.currentPerson.Rating

let c = Rating - 1
```

Im trying to get the `value x` of `self.currentPerson.Rating` and subtract 1 from `value x`. But Im only getting the error bellow.

> **Error** : Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'NSNumber' and 'Int'

**Question** : How do I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: by not using a `NSNumber` but getting its `intValue` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved.

By simply adding `.intValue`.

```
var Rating = self.currentPerson.Rating

let c = Rating.intValue - 1
```

> Cred @luk2302